# What is the right way to change icon from selected to unselected in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating add to cart logic, so I created a function which is added items in the cart, but I don't understand how properly change icons from unselected to selected. So I was trying to do something like that:

```
 void addToCart(Item prod) {
    print('it works');
    products.add(prod);
    print('it works2');
  }

  Widget iconChage(){
    if(_isPressed == true){
      return Icon(Icons.ten_k);
    }else{

      return Icon(Icons.eleven_mp);
    }
```

But it doesn't work when I put it to the widget tree. What is the right way to change the icon from selected to unselected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

Make a `bool` to use as `condition`:

```
bool isPressed = true;
```

Then use your `icon` like this:

```
Icon(isPressed? Icons.ten_k : Icons.eleven_mp)
```

When want to `toggle` the icon just simply do this:

```
setState(()=> isPressed = !isPressed)
```